# MS Graph beta API onlineMeetings attendanceReports not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get the recent changes to the MS Graph beta API to return a collection of meetingAttendanceReports using /attendanceReports (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-beta). I have tried this in Graph Explorer and also in a C# console app in VS, but cannot get it working.

The (Graph Explorer) request is as follows:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/8b16954b-5dcb-4395-89bb-be879c0f8f77/onlineMeetings/MSo4YjE2OTU0Yi01ZGJiLTQzOTUtODliYi1iZTg3OWMwZjhmNzcqMCoqMTe6bWVldGluZ19Zek0yTnpVNU5ERXRNRFUwT1MwME5UZzRMVGszTXpZdE16QmxNV1JqTmpCak5tRXhAdGhyZWFkLnYy/attendanceReports

The response I am getting is "BadRequest" : "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: String".

The online (Teams) meeting is successfully returned if I remove /attendanceReports resulting in the following request:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/8b16954b-5dcb-4395-89bb-be879c0f8f77/onlineMeetings/MSo4YjE2OTU0Yi01ZGJiLTQzOTUtODliYi1iZTg3OWMwZjhmNzcqMCoqMTe6bWVldGluZ19Zek0yTnpVNU5ERXRNRFUwT1MwME5UZzRMVGszTXpZdE16QmxNV1JqTmpCak5tRXhAdGhyZWFkLnYy

I have spent days trying to get this working. Although similar error responses can be found by searching online, none of them seem to relate to this particular situation. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Are you using user delegated or app permissions?

Comment: If you are using application permission for this API, then tenant administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user. This authorizes the app configured in the policy to fetch online meetings and/or online meeting artifacts on behalf of that user (with the user ID specified in the request path).

Comment: I have tried both methods, with the same result for both.

Comment: Could you please try like below query and check if it helps: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userid}/onlineMeetings/MSpkYzE3Njc0Yy04MWQ5LTRhZGItYmZ/meetingAttendanceReport`

Comment: That only gives you the last report. I'm looking to get all the reports for recurring meetings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Created an onlineMeeting using Graph API and got the meeting ID from the response
2. Then by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request) doc tried to get attendanceReports and got proper response.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: The meetings I am trying to get this data from are recurring, plus they were not created using the API. They were created in Outlook using the Teams Meeting option. I can find and return the onlineMeeting successfully, but if I cannot get attendanceReports to work.

Comment: Again i created a recurring meeting event from outlook. Got the JoinUrl and run the below query using graph to get meeting id: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq 'xxxxxx'`. Then  to get attendanceReports followed the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request) provided and got correct response as well.

Comment: Yes, I cannot understand why it does not work.

Comment: Did you create the recurring event from the Outlook application, or online? Mine were created using the desktop application.

Comment: I created using Outlook application.

Comment: Everything mentioned above is what I had already tried. I know it should work. But it doesn't.

Comment: @fatherjack - Could you please reverify your API permissions and other configuration and test it once.

Comment: I performed some further troubleshooting last night. There's 28 recurring meetings that I'm interested in. I moved to a more substantial test, attempting to get attendance reports for all of them. Around 5 of them worked, with the other 23 returning the error in the original post.

Comment: I have since compared the results when GETting a meeting that works with attendanceReports with one that does not,. I cannot see any differences (apart from the obvious ID, subject, start time etc.). I'm stumped.

Comment: We tried with quite a few instances of recurring meeting as you mentioned and each time we got correct response without any error.